# Get value at a given point (latitude/longitude)

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm working with the [RESOLVE Ecoregions 2017 dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/RESOLVE_ECOREGIONS_2017), which is a dataset that depicts 800+ terrestrial ecoregions that represent the Earth. I simply need to specify a given point (longitude and latitude) and in return I need the given ecoregion (ECO_ID, the ecoregion unique ID).

Just having the boundaries of each ecoregion would help (I'm guessing that there must be a library that would then be able to tell me if yes or no a point is inside a polygon), but I can't manage to get them.

I'm working with Python, but here's an example using GEE of what I would like to obtain:

```
longitude = 4  # random longitude
latitude = 44  # random latitude

ecoregions = ee.FeatureCollection('RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017')  # the dataset
point = ee.Geometry.Point([longitude, latitude])  # not sure I should process like that

def point_to_ecoregion(ecoregions, point):
   xxx
   xxx  # some code
   xxx
   return ecoregion_id

id = point_to_ecoregion(ecoregions, point)  # this would give me the id of the ecoregion in which the point is located
```

I've really looked everywhere (at least I tried), but I can't find anything that helps me.

Comment: If you just want the boundaries you can download the data ~ https://storage.googleapis.com/teow2016/Ecoregions2017.zip

Comment: With the shapefile data above, you could convert to PostgreSQL w/ GIS support and query points that way.

Comment: I'd suggest using `shapely`. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399381/whats-the-fastest-way-of-checking-if-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-in-python) example.

Comment: I assume you're using the file on Google Earth Engine, and don't have a downloaded copy?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody that helped me!

Thanks to you, I managed to obtain the ecoregion of a given point. Here is my code in Python:

```
def get_ecoregion(lat,long):
   ecoregions = gpd.read_file("path/to/file/given/by/nmtoken/Ecoregions2017.shp")
   geometry = ecoregions["geometry"]
   point = Point(long, lat)
   point_in_ecoregion = geometry.contains(point)
   ind = point_in_ecoregion[point_in_ecoregion == True].index[0]
   ecoregion = ecoregions.iloc[ind]["ECO_ID"]
   return ecoregion

get_ecoregion(43.779, 3.812)

OUTPUT: 799
```

It's not optimized (for example you shouldn't load the file inside the method, but I will run this function only once so it's "ok"), but at least it works, thanks to you.

Comment: Wait, if you can do `read_file("path/to/file/given/by/nmtoken/Ecoregions2017.shp")`, you can just download the entire file locally, no?

Comment: Yes I could, but would it change something? My problem was that I didn't have access to this file (the shapefile of the dataset). I was only working with the earth-engine-api but I couldn't obtain the results I got with nmtoken's file (I imagine that it should be possible, but I couldn't).

Comment: Oh, I just meant that you essentially solved the problem by "downloading" data locally, not inside Google Earth Engine itself. If that was a petabyte file, for example, your technique probably wouldn't work

Comment: Yes @BarryCarter you are right. That is why I'm not 100% satisfied with this method, but at least it's working. But indeed, if the file was larger, even this solution would not have worked.